# Good practice to import images in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am adding multiple images in my web page by placing each image in same directory that of components (see screenshot) How can I place the image files in another folder and then access them inside my components.

content.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import java from './java.png';
    import neural from './neural.png';
    import future from './future.gif';
    import neuralnet from './neuralnet.jpg';
    import dsa from './dsa.png';
    import dl from './dl.jpg';
    import ml from './ml.jpg';
    import python from './python.png';
    import ai from './ai.jpg';


<img className="futuregif" src={future} alt="gif" height="240" width="320"></img>
<img className="javacardimg" src={java} alt="Java" height="65" width="65"></img>
 <img className="neuralcardimg" src={neural} alt="neural" height="65" width="65"></img>

and so on.. for all other images
```

Components and image files are getting mixed together is there any other specific way to do it by making a image folder but then what should be the path in `src=""`.

File structure:

[image]

Comment: Just create an folder (for instance `images`) and access it by `import neural from './images/neural.png';`.

Comment: @Striped I had tried it earlier but what will be the path in `src=""`.

Comment: It will be `src={neural}`.

Comment: @Striped Will it be `src="neural"` or ` src="images.neural"`

Comment: Like I said it will be `src={neural}` like you actually do.

Comment: @Striped Ok let me check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify my comment.

Create a directory `assets` containing all your assets like images.
Then import the right path and load your content like:

```
import neural from './assets/images/neural.png';

class myComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div><img src={neural} alt=""/></div>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my point of view you can create a js file and `export const imageName`. in const you can specify your image path.

**constant.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import java from './java.png';

export const javaImg = java;
```

Then in your component file you need to import that js file and you can use those const according to your requirement.

**Component**

```
import constant from './constant';

class x extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log(constant.javaImg);
    }
}

export default x;
```

If you are importing images in same component it'll work but the component will become a lengthy and complex looking.

so my suggestion is like this.

Comment: yes my component is lengthy see content.js in my question. Can you give an example in you answer and how will the path in `src=""` be ?

Comment: Check my answer now

Comment: Once I export then what should be the path in `src=""`

Comment: your image path present in `constant.javaImg`